# Javascript game - cannot read "y" property of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection, 2d-games

So I was making this game today, and everything works perfectly, but sometimes this error shows up. I know what it means, and I've had it before, but this time it makes no sense. The game works perfectly fine, but sometimes when the bullet collides with the enemy the game freezes. I don't even know what to try anymore. Btw, if the error doesn't show up right away, just keep playing. Here's the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Space shooter</title>
<style>
* {
    margin:0;
}
canvas {
    background: url("http://www.ufointernationalproject.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/space-03.jpg");
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1350" height="630"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    lastShot = Date.now(),
    fireRate = 120,
    bullets = [],
    enemies = [],
    enemySpeed = 1.5,
    bulletSpeed = 20,
    player = {
        x: 600,
        y: 250,
        leftPressed: false,
        rightPressed: false,
        upPressed: false,
        downPressed: false,
        spacePressed: false,
        speed: 5
    };
var playerImage = new Image();
playerImage.src = "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-jGC08Dy0zg8/U405cNq1-MI/AAAAAAAABqU/38d5rmV1S8Y/s1600/redfighter0006.png";
var enemyImage = new Image();
enemyImage.src = "https://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/partartspace/screenshots/Spaceship14.png/1";

function spawnEnemes() {
    enemies.push({
        x:Math.floor(Math.random() * 1250) + 1,  
        y:-100
    })
}
setInterval(spawnEnemes, 500);

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(playerImage, player.x,player.y, 100, 100);

    if (player.leftPressed) {
        player.x -= player.speed;
    }
    if (player.rightPressed) {
        player.x += player.speed;
    }
    if (player.upPressed) {
        player.y -= player.speed;
    }
    if (player.downPressed) {
        player.y += player.speed;
    }
    if (player.spacePressed && Date.now() - lastShot > fireRate) {
        bullets.push({
            x: player.x+50,
            y: player.y
        });
        lastShot = Date.now();
    }   

    bullets.forEach(function(bullet){       
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(bullet.x, bullet.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill(); 
        bullet.y -= bulletSpeed;                    
    }); 

    enemies.forEach(function(enemy){
        ctx.drawImage(enemyImage, enemy.x, enemy.y, 100,100);
        enemy.y += enemySpeed;  
    }); 

    for (var enemy = 0; enemy < enemies.length; enemy ++){
        if(player.x < enemies[enemy].x + 80 &&
               player.x + 80 > enemies[enemy].x &&
               player.y < enemies[enemy].y + 65 &&
               player.y + 100  > enemies[enemy].y)
            {
                document.location.reload();
            }
        for (var bullet = 0; bullet < bullets.length; bullet ++) {
            if(bullets[bullet].y < enemies[enemy].y + 70 &&
               bullets[bullet].y > enemies[enemy].y &&
               bullets[bullet].x < enemies[enemy].x + 100 &&
               bullets[bullet].x > enemies[enemy].x)    
            {
                bullets.splice(bullet, 1);
                enemies.splice(enemy, 1);               
            }                   
        }   
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        player.leftPressed = true;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        player.rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        player.upPressed = true;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        player.downPressed = true;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        player.spacePressed = true;
    }
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        player.leftPressed = false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        player.rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        player.upPressed = false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        player.downPressed = false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        player.spacePressed = false;
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make this a snippet

Comment: At which line the error occurs?

Comment: at the 92nd line.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined
    at draw` at line 102

Comment: Sorry, it's 92nd on my local file, but here it's on the 102nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be when you splice. As you don't exit the loops, you end up accessing invalid positions after a removal.

Comment: I just added break after splicing and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much man!